# Mountain Lion to PC on workgroup not seen?

Tags: osx-lion

Mountain Lion (Macbook Pro Retina)does not show in Network Panel on WIN 7 PC.  Macbook Pro Retina shows Win 7 PC on Finder.

I have a  Macbook Pro.8 OS10.6.8 that shows on Finder and can be accessed by the Retina Macbook Pro.  Neither Macs show on WIN 7 PC.

I had it working after talking to Apple Support, but now it's not. I don't recall all the steps the support guy had me make to get the Retina working.
Why would Apple change the Network Protocol from OS10.6.8 for OS10.8?

Answer (score 1):

*The existential question of "why would Apple change..." is rather off-topic*

As for MacOSX and workgroups, go to **System Preferences**, **Network**, the active or relevant network connection (ie, **Ethernet** or **WiFi**), **Advanced**, and look in the **WINS** tab.

You may also need to enable SMB sharing if you are seeking to have filesharing from the Macs to Windows machines. **System Preferences**, **Sharing**, check **File Sharing** and (while on the File Sharing line) look in **Options** for **Share files and folders using SMB (Windows)**